# laravel redirect if logged in

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, laravel-5.1

i am using laravel 5.1.8.
i am making a login/registration system.
i made a controller named AdminController and protect it with middleware.

but i am using laravel's default AuthController which methods and classes are located in different locations. where routes are:

```
Route::Controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
]);

get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
get('profile', 'AdminController@profile');
get('article', 'AdminController@article');
```

users cannot access AdminController without logging in. its redirected to login page. but i want, if a logged in user typed the address of login page or registration on the address bar of browser, the page will redirected to AdminController.

when i try to do this, it looking for '/home' and gives errors. i want to make it '/admin'.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

go to 
`App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`
then change it from

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

to

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to implement middleware, for example:

`Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware('guest');`

Comment: This still works with 5.6. Thanks! Couldn't find the bugger.

Comment: In Laravel 8 you don't need to modify it, just go to your `RouteServiceProvider`and change from `public const HOME = '/home'` to the desired path `public const HOME = '/desired-path'`

Comment: and then in router, something like ```Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(route('login'));
});```

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your `AuthController`:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
```

This tells all the redirect methods in the various traits to redirect there instead of to `/home`.

Answer (score 4):

You can check using auth function.

```
public function checkLogin()
{

    if (auth()->user()) 
    {
         return redirect(route('home'));
    }
    else
    {
           return redirect(route('login'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Include `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class` middleware in $middlewareGroups "web" array after `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` middleware

then modify your redirect path in `handle()` method of RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        //check if authenticate && second is condition when we need to redirect i.e, 
         if(Auth::guard($guard)->check() && $request->route()->named('login') ) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

when a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the /home URI, which you will need to register a route to handle. You can customize the post-authentication redirect location by defining a redirectPath property on the AuthController:

protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';

Comment: create route dashboard