# Laravel 5 redirect if logged

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect my user to my custom url, if he visits the login page, and is already logged in. I put my code in `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` but it not working

```
/**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // my code...
    }
```

Somebody can help me, tks!!!!

Comment: what does that `// my code` does?

Comment: Are you using the using authentication system shiped with laravel, or did you create your own one ?

Comment: duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129874/laravel-redirect-if-logged-in

Comment: Toan why are you not responding to comments? whats inside // my code..., why do you have to mess up `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate`

Answer (score 1):

You can use guest middleware on login route:

```
Route::get('login', [
    'middleware' => 'guest',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin' //or any other action you have defined
]);
```

This will redirect a logged-in user trying to visit login page to `/home` url but you can change the path in App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your controller method Auth::check()

```
public function loginPage() {
if (Auth::check()) {
  // The user is logged in...
  return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

[See](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

Answer (score 0):

By adding in LoginController construct it will execute when login is called.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        // This will check if user is authenticated
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/to-your-desired-location');
        }
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
```