# Laravel: Redirect login & register if logged in?

Tags: laravel

I'm struggling to get the login/register pages to redirect the user if already logged in.

in routes.php

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('hud', 'HomeController@index')->name('hud');
    Route::get('search', 'HomeController@search')->name('search');
    Route::get('profile', 'UsersController@index')->name('profile');
    Route::get('clients', 'ClientsController@index')->name('clients');
    Route::delete('clients/{id}', 'ClientsController@destroy');
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController', array('only' => array('show')));

});
```

I've tried no_auth and it just breaks. Am I missing something?

Comment: did you try `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () { ... }` ?

Comment: Why you want login page if user is already logged in.

Comment: If the user visits the login page it asks for login again

Comment: Why do you want to re login. Why not you logout instead and then redirect to login.

Comment: If the user is logged in and revisits the login page they get the login form. I want them to be redirected if they happen to go back to the login page.

Comment: I am sorry i dont understand why people go for login if already login ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut OP's point is: Once the user is logged in, He must not be able to see the `/login` page. Even if he's deliberately trying to see that page.

He should be redirected to `/dashboard` or something rather than letting him see the `/login` form.

It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the redirect path for when a given visitor is authenticated user.

You can do so in: `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`

Example:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

[Stackoverflow: laravel redirect if logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129874/laravel-redirect-if-logged-in)

Comment: I have this in that file:

`public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect already registered user to Homepage whenever they try to hit `/login`.

Here's how laravel tries to achieve that.

1. Firstly this is achieved through `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`.

However a key to this middleware is registered to `guest` in this file `app\Http\Kernel.php` under array `protected $routeMiddleware`.

2. Then in your login controller presumably at `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

In the `construct` method, We have something like this:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```